# Python Scrapy - Pass scraped data from first URL to second URL and scrape data

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have looked at several posts on StackOverflow but still, do not quite understand how I can do this. In Scrapy, I am scraping books from one URL. For each record of the scraped books, I want to pass that to another website's search-field and get a certain element from the website. However, Scrapy seems to be stuck on the first website, and not retrieving results from the second. (I am trying basically to replicate in Scrapy what could be very easily done with Selenium - it's just slower with Selenium& BS).

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
from datetime
import datetime
from timeit
import default_timer as timer
from fake_useragent
import UserAgent


start = timer()
d1 = datetime.now()

book = []
country = []


stmp = []
items = []
today = datetime.now()
tt = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S')

class CoinsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "proxies"
custom_settings = {
  'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3,
  'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 3,
  'HTTPCACHE_ENABLED': True,
  'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
  },
  'DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS': {
    'Referer': 'http://www.google.com'
  }
}

def start_requests(self):
  url = "https://www.book.net/"
  yield scrapy.Request(url = url, callback = self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
  for row in response.css("#booklisttable > tbody:nth-child(1) tr"):
    b = row.css('.title::text')[0].extract()
    book.append(b)

try:
  request = scrapy.Request('https://www.searchbook.com/international',
  callback = self.parse_gua,cb_kwargs = dict(main_url = response.url))
  yield request

  print(response.headers)
  print(response.css)

  check = response.css('.fc-today__dayofmonth::text').extract()
  print(check)
except:
  pass


crts = row.css('.country::text')[0].extract()
country.append(crts)

tstmp = str(d1)
stmp.append(tstmp)

item = {
  "Title": book,
  "Country": country,
  "Timex": stmp,
}

test_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(item, orient = 'columns').replace('\n', '', regex = True)
test_df['Joined'] = test_df['Title'] + ':' + test_df['Country']

items.append(test_df)

result = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(items[i]) for i in range(len(items))], ignore_index = True)
with open('my_books_' + tt + '.csv', 'a', newline = '') as f:
  result.to_csv(f)

print("Completed")
end = timer()
elapse = end - start
print("It Took" + str(elapse))
```

Sorry if my question is to basic, but if someone could point to a link in the documentation, or a sample that would be great!

Comment: Where is parse_gua ?

Comment: Please, provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and format your code with the correct indentation.